# using actionPerformed fails because a method in it can throw exceptions

Tags: java

SOLVED! Thanks all for quick answers, the problem was that i thought that if u catch an exception that u still have to add throws Exception to the header
^^ pretty dumb off me, thanks again!
------------------------------------ORIGINAL POST-------
Hello,
I have a method load(), this method throws IOException's.
I'm trying to make this:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Load")){
           load();
       }
    }
```

the problem is, I should add throws IOException to the actionPerformed, but if I do so.
I get an error saying: "The class isnt declared abstract or doesn't override public void actioPerformed()

Comment: Don't change your question once you get an answer. The answers no no longer make sense. If you must edit your question, post it at the bottom under an EDIT line or something.

Comment: @user545236 and @Falmarri, The accepted practice for answering your own question is to post an actual answer and not edit the original question at all. Question edits should be for clarifications, adding more information (such as sample code), etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to work out what you want to happen if `load` throws an `IOException`. The method *calling* `actionPerformed` isn't expecting an `IOException`, so it can't possibly handle it.

Can you handle it, e.g. by displaying an error message and letting the user try again? If so, put a `try/catch` block in `actionPerformed` and handle it that way.

If you can't, you *could* catch the exception and wrap it in a `RuntimeException`. That's generally a fairly harsh way of dealing with the exception, but in some cases it's the best approach. Swing will catch the exception and log it, so in this case it may not be much help... but you may be able to change that default behaviour too.

Comment: In Swing, there's an uncaught exception handler, and the RuntimeException will end up being logged to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't simply surround the call to `load()` with a `try`-`catch` block? For example:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Load")) {
        try {
            load();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // Handle the error here
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that you have some behavior you can execute if `load()` fails. What does `load()` do? What should your application do if it can't load?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to throw the IOException, or surround the method that does (presumably getActionCommand()?) with a try/catch.

Comment: The OP says in his question that `load()` is the method that throws IOExceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think of how to handle the `IOException` within the context of `actionPerformed()`.

One approach would be to use a try/catch block, and in the catch display a dialog that tells the user that something went wrong. Better if you can translate the exception into something meaningful, and best if you can give the user some way to recover from the problem.

Incidentally, if you're doing some long-running IO operation, you shouldn't be doing it on the event dispatch thread -- it will cause delays in your GUI. And rather than sharing one `ActionListener` between multiple actions (with the if condition to see which action you've been called by), create a subclass of `AbstractAction` for each.